# Is nesting types considered bad practice?

Tags: design, c#, readability

As noted by the title, is nesting types (e.g. enumerated types or structures in a class) considered bad practice or not? When you run Code Analysis in Visual Studio it returns the following message which implies it is:

> Warning   34  CA1034 : Microsoft.Design :
>   Do not nest type
>   'ClassName.StructueName'.
>   Alternatively, change its
>   accessibility so that it is not
>   externally visible.

However, when I follow the recommendation of the Code Analysis I find that there tend to be a lot of structures and enumerated types floating around in the application that might only apply to a single class or would only be used with that class. As such, would it be appropriate to nest the type sin that case, or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: This question is VERY closely related to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/34067  I'm torn on whether to close this as a duplicate...

Comment: @Walter - They are close but I've heard the question brought up separately for nesting classes in classes and nesting all other types in classes separately so it couldn't hurt. As it turns out, I didn't find that question when I did my search originally.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nested types are not bad. The warning you are receiving is not suggesting you never have a nested type. It is simply indicating that your nested type should use an appropriate access modifier and code location.

If the nested type is truly only used inside the containing class (i.e. it is an internal data container or status indicator), then set its access modifier to private.

If the nested type is part of one or more method signatures, then it is not in fact local to the containing class. It represents a message being passed to or from instances of the containing class. In this case, it is arguably better to move the nested type out of the containing class, and give it a more open access modifier such as internal or public.

In short, the warning appears to be recommending that you make local types private, and shared types should stand alone.

Comment: The internal modifier is what I've been doing in most cases, cleans things up a bit, but there are a lot of them floating around in the application.

Answer (score 2):

If it is used solely by that class it should be made private and that is exactly what the message is suggesting.

Comment: In some cases that is done, but in other cases an enumerated type is being used in method calls attached to the class. Likewise, I've also seen structures being used for method class if the number of parameters exceeds a given number.

Answer (score 1):

The warning about nesting types was one of the first "suggestions" I received some time back after having enabled the Code Analysis. It was also the reason why I switched it off.

Some suggestions are really foreign as though they come from another planet.

I do put enumeration inside classes to keep things logically together.

Think of it this way: if nesting types would have been absolute evil in all cases, why would the language designers have implemented it in the first place? Because it is useful in many cases and in that regard the said warning is merely a pointing out that something in your code might not be optimal. If it applies or not is up to you to decide.

Comment: A namespace should be your logical grouping for the enum; not the class

Comment: Well in some situations I find it inconvenient.

Comment: If you are currently placing the enum within the class, moving it outside of the class so it resides within the namespace takes all of a CTRL+X coupled with a CTRL+V...not sure how it would become inconvenient?

Comment: I sometimes put my enums inside classes. I think there are legitimate reasons to it - its not a strict rule.

Comment: @rmx I have never used an enum within a single class; it is always used within multiple classes, so defining it within the namespace as its own entity makes much more sense.

Comment: Nesting the command class inside the handler class documents very well that those two belongs together. That is lost if you move the nested class to the outer scope. Yes, you can keep those in the same file, but it's too easy to let tools like ReSharper to separate them unintentionally.

Answer (score 0):

**No**

A good example in C# is IEnumerable where other classes doesn't need to know the exact class it  returns, only that it is a IEnumerator. So it makes sense to make it an nested class otherwise you might have lots of small classes floating around in intellisense that implements IEnumerator

Comment: In some cases, run-time efficiency can be improved if a compiler knows the type returned by `GetEnumerator()`; for that reason, `List<T>.GetEnumerator()` returns `List<T>.Enumerator()`.  If had been some way to ask the compiler to use some other named method, it might have been better to have that method e.g. `ForEachGetEnumerator()` return `List<T>.Enumerator` and have `GetEnumerator()` return `IEnumerator<T>`, but no mechanism exists for that.